# Flat tax on an evolving value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I am going to deposit 261.33€ on an account each month.

Each month, 0.1% of the total value of the account is debited. So for the first month with the account starting at 0, it would be 261.33 * 0.1% = 0.2613€.

After a year, 3200€ have been deposited. What is the formula to figure out how much has been debited by these monthly 0.1% ?

Comment: Closer to the finance stack exchange, but I could figure it out.

Comment: Let me know if you find out the formula... I'm not good at maths. In the mean time I have written a C program to calculate things iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is $$3135.96-\Bigg(261.33\sum_{i=1}^{12}0.999^i\Bigg)$$

Where 3135.96€ is the actual amount of 261.33€ times 12.  It gives  approximately 20.31€ if you don't lose precision (okay cut precision a little to do it on a basic phone calculator) . There are easier ways to approximate financial math as well.

Comment: That's what my program gave ! I still don't understand the formula though, lol. What to do with x ? Does it take value 1,2...12 ? And what to do between 261.33 and 0.999 ? I'm wondering how this could have been programmed

Comment: it's a sum from 1 to 12 of 0.999 raised to that power, times by 261.33 the regular payment, and then subtract from the total payment without negative interest.

Comment: screwed up variables in my head might be why.